# Trying to make selectInput after getting the data from query using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make an app that would take product ID from input field and then download data from server and use that data to create a selectInput.
My UI part:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Alternatives"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("text1",
                label = h3("Enter product ID:"),
                value = "ID"),

      actionButton('run', 'Run'),

      hr(),
      selectInput("selectinput",
                  label = "Alternatives:",
                  choices = choices_for_input
                  )
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
```

My server part:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    alldata <- data_request(as.numeric(input$text1)) #getting data from server
    })

     ### putting data into correspoding datatables
  fields <- as.data.table(do.call(rbind, alldata$fields))
  setnames(fields,
           c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"),
           c('prod_id', 'field', 'item1', 'alternative', 'score'))
  scores <- as.data.table(do.call(rbind, alldata$scores))
  setnames(scores,
           c("V1", "V2"),
           c("prod_id", "score"))

    ### list for selectInput choices
  choices_for_input <- scores$prod_id
}
```

but I get an error:

```
object 'choices_for_input' not found
```

I could use some default value like `NO VALUES` inside my choices to begin with and later update the choice list, but I want the selectInput only appear after all the data is prepared with all the right selections. But I am not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass variables from your server to your ui and visa/versa (well... there are ways). What you can do is update your `selectInput` choices after you have loaded your data.

In your `ui` you can set your choices to an empty vector:

```
selectInput("selectinput", label = "Alternatives:", choices = c())
```

and in your `server` you can updated your choices (after you loaded the data) with:

```
updateSelectInput(session, 'selectinput', choices = choices_for_input)
```

---

If you really want to hide the `selectInput` before you loaded your data, you can use the `shinyjs` library:

1. Add the `useShinyjs()` function somewhere in your `ui`.
2. Wrap `selectInput('selectinput', ...)` in the `hidden()` function of `shinyjs`.
3. Add `shinyjs::show('selectinput')` in your `server` after you updated the choices.

**Working example**

```
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), #add shinyjs functionalty
  titlePanel("Alternatives"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text1",
                label = h3("Enter product ID:"),
                value = "ID"),
      actionButton('run', 'Run'),
      hr(),
      hidden(selectInput("selectinput", label = "Alternatives:", choices = c()))# hide selectinput on load
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    Sys.sleep(2) # sleep some time
    scores = data.frame(prod_id=1:10) # create random data
    updateSelectInput(session, 'selectinput', choices = scores$prod_id) # update choices
    shinyjs::show('selectinput') # show selectinput
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Another way is to use `renderUI(selectInput(...))` in the server function.